# Why does wprintf separate Unicode ligature into two different graphemes?

Tags: c, unicode, wchar, ligature

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#define USE_W
int main()
{
#ifdef USE_W
    const wchar_t *ae_utf16 = L"\x00E6 & ASCII text ae\n";
    wprintf(ae_utf16);
#else
    const char *ae_utf8 = "\xC3\xA6 & ASCII text ae\n";
    printf(ae_utf8);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ae & ASCII text ae

While printf produces correct UTF-8 output:

> æ & ASCII text ae

You can test this [here](http://ideone.com/giKg5C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` just sends raw bytes to your terminal; it does not know anything about encodings. If your terminal happens to be configured to interpret that as UTF-8, it will show the right characters.

`wprintf`, on the other hand, does know about encodings. It [behaves as though](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/) it uses the function [wcrtomb](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcrtomb/), which encodes a wide character (`wchar_t`) into a multibyte sequence, *depending on the current locale*. If the default locale happens to be `"C"`, which is quite minimalistic, the character `æ` gets converted to the "more or less equivalent" byte sequence `ae`.

If you set the locale explicitly to something using UTF-8, like `"en_US.UTF-8"`, the output [is as expected](http://ideone.com/AdSDsR). Of course, the set of supported locales differs per system, so it's no good to hardcode this.

Comment: Thank you for information about the requirement to set a locale before using wprintf.

Comment: This works on Linux. On Windows, trying to set the locale to a UTF-8 code page [will fail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx). AFAICT, `wprintf` cannot be used to print a UTF-8 string there. [WriteConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx) is required.